# Puppeteer enter value to input form

Tags: puppeteer

how can i put data if the form field is like this.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" data-id="emailAddress" autocomplete="email" class="AuthenticationModal__AuthenticationTextInput-li0874-28 kuwMeF WebsiteTextInput-sc-1k4jzwj-3 kZlRsK" value="">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" data-id="password" autocomplete="current-password" class="AuthenticationModal__AuthenticationTextInput-li0874-28 kuwMeF WebsiteTextInput-sc-1k4jzwj-3 kZlRsK" value="">
```

tried using this but did not work.

```
await page.type('[data-id="emailAddress"]', 'test_account@gmail.com')
await page.type('[data-id="password"]', '12345678')
await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true, path: 'website.png' })
await browser.close();
```

test_account@gmail.com is not display in screenshot.

thanks in advance.

note: im just a newbie usin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if this code worked perfectly or not.

```
const emailInput = '[placeholder="Email Address"][autocomplete="email"]'
const emailWords = 'test_account@gmail.com'
await page.waitForSelector( emailInput, { timeout: 0 })
await page.focus(emailInput)
await page.keyboard.type(emailWords)

const passwordInput = 'input[placeholder="Password"][autocomplete="current-password"]'
const passwordWords = '12345678'
await page.waitForSelector( passwordInput, { timeout: 0 })
await page.focus(passwordInput)
await page.keyboard.type(passwordWords)

await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true, path: 'website.png' })
await browser.close()
```

Sure you can't waitForNavigation after the navigation occured.
You can use waitForNavigation before you click the submit within the form.
Don't use any await here, because it's already a promise.

```
Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 1000000 })
    page.click('input[type="submit"]')
])
```

Something like that.
Tell me if this works or not.
And don't forget to select this answer as the correct answer, it it's works perfectly.

Comment: the email show to the right form field except the password was type on the same form field as email address. not sure whats wrong on this.

Comment: btw what im trying to do is to login to wish.com and do search on their page and scrap the content which as i said from above i am just newbie on using nodejs and pupppeteer but i am enjoying it.

Comment: If you're login to wish.com, then you can change the `emailInput` selector to `'[placeholder="Email Address"][autocomplete="email"]'`
. 
I've change the code above, try it again, and don't forget to double check if you mistakenly type or copy pasting my code above.

Comment: I've also adding selector for the password for the correct one.

Please tell me if this worked or not.

Comment: now my next problem is the submit buttom. looks like he dont use any submit type on his form from modal this is his login button <div class="AuthenticationModal__AuthenticationButtonWrapper-li0874-8 AuthenticationModal__DefaultAuthenticationButton-li0874-15 cfjbky"><div class="AuthenticationModal__AuthenticationButtonText-li0874-9 AuthenticationModal__DefaultAuthenticationButtonText-li0874-16 klGoTA">Log In</div></div>

Comment: i made it work by using "await page.keyboard.press('Enter');" but when i add this "await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 1000000 });" it give me always a timeout error not sure what wrong.

Comment: I've edit my code and answer above. Please select my answer as correct if you found this works perfectly in your machine.

Comment: page.click('input[type="submit"]')
            ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loade
r.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32) 
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727
:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1
047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11